# Cannot make namespaces work in go-socketio

Tags: go, socket.io

I'm using https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io to create a socket.io server. I'm trying to create a namespace, but I'm not able to connect to the namespace from the client side.

Server:

```
func registerHandlers(server *socketio.Server) {
    server.Of("room1").On("connection", connectionHandler)
}

func connectionHandler(so socketio.Socket) {
    log.Println("on connection")
    so.Join("chat")
    so.On("chat message", func(msg string) {
        so.BroadcastTo("chat", "chat message", msg)
    })
}
```

Client:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/room1");
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you start an HTTP server? e.g. `log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))`

Comment: @AttilaO. Yes, of course. Connections to root namespace is working well.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace functionality in that package seems to be broken. See:

- [Issue 59](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/issues/59)
- [Issue 138](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/issues/138)

Answer (score 0):

You want to prefix your namespaces with a slash.
The code you gave as an example would become:

```
func registerHandlers(server *socketio.Server) {
    server.Of("/room1").On("connection", connectionHandler)
}
```

Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

use this sample :

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)


func main() {


    server, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // server.SetMaxConnection(9000000);

    server.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {
        log.Println("on connection")
        log.Println(so.Id())



        so.On("CHAT", func(msg string) {
            log.Println("CHAT +++++++>"   , msg)
        })


        so.On("server", func(msg string) {
            log.Println("serverpublic  =====>  "   , msg)
        })



        so.On("disconnection", func() {
            log.Println("on disconnect")
        })

    })


    server.On("error", func(so socketio.Socket, err error) {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    })


    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    log.Println("Serving at localhost:16900...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":15900", nil))
}//main
```

Answer (score -5):

**On Server side**

By default socket.io works in the default namespace (/)

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

You than create namespaces from the default.

```
var nmspc = io.of('/namespace');
```

Now you can emit and receive messages within your custum namespace.

```
nmspc.on('connection', function(socket){
     socket.on('', function(){ 
        ...
     });

}
```

**On the client** side you can connect to the namespace with the following

```
var socket = io('/namespace').connect('http://url:PORT');
```

I hope this covers your question around namespaces within socket.io